# New raspberry pi 2 B not able to boot into GUI

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I just purchased new raspberry pi and tried to install raspbian using Noobs.
So the installation goes successfully and I boot into raspbian GUI successfully and make changes to raspi-config like to ask for the password when booting into GUI and enable various option like SSH,SCI and more. Then it reboots and gives me following error:

```
Raspberry pi Fatal server error: could not create lock file in /inp/.1xd-lock Please consult the X.org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help 
init: giving up 
init: unable to connect to X server: Connection not sucessfull 
init: server error nuth: error in locking authority file /home/pi/.xauthority
```

I have done this process so many time it is giving me same error every time. Any suggestion.......

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.xauthority` file to make sure it's owned by the user you're logging in as rather than root. If it's owned by root, you can either change the ownership, or simply delete it and it will be recreated next time you attempt a login.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before!

It is likely your .xauthority file is corrupted, or root owns that file which means it won't let you boot into the GUI. Try this code and it seemed to work for me...

```
sudo chown -R pi:pi /home/pi
```

Basically what this is doing is it is reverting all the files' permission settings back to you, so the .Xauthority file for your account will be yours again.
BUT...
If the actual file itself is corrupt, then do this:

```
xauth -b
```

.Xauthority is not needed on startup, so it is safe to just delete it off your SD card, since a new version will be generated when you boot into the GUI.